# What's the word that means someone who can't adapt to nature?

Tags: synonyms

I heard a word some months ago describing someone who was not the type who could handle being dropped in the middle of nowhere and surviving. I forget if it was an adjective or a noun - I think it was a noun.

Answer (score 2):

Greenhorn (green meaning immature) is the word I remember from Cowboy films.

> [etymonline.com](http:///index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=greenhorn&searchmode=none)> 
>   greenhorn (n.) 
>       mid-15c.,
>   "horn of an animal recently killed," also "young horned animal," from green (adj.) in sense of "new, fresh, recent" + horn
>   (n.). Applied to **new soldiers** from c. 1650; extended to **any
>   inexperienced person by 1680s.**

Tenderfoot came into popularity with *Scouting for Boys*

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenderfoot
>
> A tenderfoot is slang for an inexperienced person, particularly one
>   who is not adapted to a rural or outdoor lifestyle setting.

tenderfoot (n.)

> 1866, American English, originally of newcomers to ranching or mining
>   districts, from tender (adj.) + foot (n.). The U.S. equivalent of what
>   in Great Britain was generally called a greenhand.
>   http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tenderfoot

Answer (score 1):

**City slicker**: A person raised in the city and accustomed to life there
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=city+slicker

Comment: This is an assumption.  Not every country boy comes from the middle of nowhere.  Not every city slicker can't handle being there.